# Save magento data in multiple languages

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to save magento data in multiple language from admin such as product,categories, cms pages and order etc. Is there ant paid or free extension to do this. For example when we have created attribute we can save it in multi language. I want this facility for all magnto data. https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3055039/9eeca2c207814aa84872f24f86477613

```
Product  > product name -> 1 eng - 2nd any national language - 2 local language of county selected in 2nd

Product  > product Description  -> 1 eng - 2nd any national language - 2 local language of county selected in 2nd
```

**For all data of magneto**

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for an extension. magento 1 is already multilingual. A store view is nothing more than an alternative language version of a store. If you need an different way of inserting/updating data then you should look into a an external PIM system